# Problem 16 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let $N(H)=\{a\in G:aHa^{-1}=H\}$. Prove that

(a) $N(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

(b) $H\subset N(H)$

**Proof:**

**(a)** 1. Let $a,b\in N(H)$ then $aHa^{-1}=H, \ bHb^{-1}=H$.

Let $x\in (ab)H(ab)^{-1}$ then $x=abhb^{-1}a^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=a(bhb^{-1})a^{-1}=ah_1a^{-1}\in H$. Thus $(ab)H(ab)^{-1}\subset H$.

If $x\in H$ then $x=aha^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=a(bh_1b^{-1})a^{-1}=(ab)h_1(ab)^{-1}\in (ab)H(ab)^{-1}.$ So $H\subset (ab)H(ab)^{-1}.$ Thus $(ab)H(ab)^{-1}=H$. We shown that $N(H)$ is closed.

2. If $a\in N(H)$ then $aHa^{-1}=H$.

Let's take $x\in a^{-1}Ha$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=a^{-1}ha$ for some $h\in H$. Since $H=aHa^{-1}$ then $h=ah_1a^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=a^{-1}(ah_1a^{-1})a=h_1\in H$. Hence $a^{-1}Ha\subset H$.

If $x\in H$ then $x=a^{-1}(axa^{-1})a=a^{-1}h_1a\in a^{-1}Ha$. Thus we have proved the converse inclusion anf eventually $H=a^{-1}Ha$.

Thus, $a^{-1}\in N(H)$ $\Rightarrow$ $N(H)$ - subgroup of $G$.

**(b)** If $a\in H$ and let's take $x\in aHa^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=aha^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$ and since $a\in H$ then $x\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $aHa^{-1}\subset H$.
If $x\in H$ then $x=a(a^{-1}xa)a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$, so $H\subset aHa^{-1}$.

We proved that if $a\in H$ then $aHa^{-1}=H$, in other words $H\subset N(H)$

Is my reasoning correct? Especially which regards to point (b).

Would be grateful for checking.

Answer (score 3):

(b) is correct but (a) is not. In (a) you prove that the center of $G$ is a subgroup, not $N(H)$. You should try this : if $a,b\in N(H)$ then $aHa^{-1}=H$ and $bHb^{-1}=H$ so $abHb^{-1}a^{-1}=aHa^{-1}=H$ so $ab\in N(H)$. Also if $aHa^{-1}=H$ then multiply with $a^{-1}$ from left and $a$ from right to show that $H=a^{-1}Ha$ so $a^{-1}\in N(H)$.

Comment: I've edited. Please take a look.

Comment: Yes, now it is correct.